# Arraylist - Resort Rental

Tags: java

When the user enters the id and resort code, how can I search in the ArrayList and get the array number that the id and resort code are stored in? I'm using a for loop.

```
for(Person pe: guestList)
{
    if ( pe.getPersonId().equals(Id))   
        System.out.println(pe.toString());
}

for(Resort re: resortList)
{
    if ( re.getResortCode().equals(resortCode)) 
        System.out.println(re.toString());
}
```

Instead of manual input:

```
Rental r1 = new Rental(guestList.get(2),resortList.get(3));
```

Below is my full program.

```
//create list of resort;
Chalet c1 = new Chalet("001","chalet1",90);
Chalet c2 = new Chalet("002","chalet2",90);
Chalet c3 = new Chalet("003","chalet3",85);
Chalet c4 = new Chalet("004","chalet4",80);
Chalet c5 = new Chalet("005","chalet5",80);
Chalet c6 = new Chalet("006","chalet6",70);

ArrayList <Resort> resortList = new ArrayList<Resort>();
resortList.add(c1);
resortList.add(c2);
resortList.add(c3);
resortList.add(c4);
resortList.add(c5);
resortList.add(c6);


//create list of guest
Person p1 = new Person("001","Alvin","88889999");
Person p2 = new Person("002","Bob","89889999");
Person p3 = new Person("003","Wendy ","98123456");

ArrayList <Person> guestList = new ArrayList<Person>();
guestList.add(p1);
guestList.add(p2);
guestList.add(p3);

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true){

    System.out.print("Enter your id: ");
    String id = console.nextLine();
    for(Person pe: guestList)
    {
        if ( pe.getPersonId().equals(id))
            System.out.println(pe.toString());

    }



    System.out.print("Enter resort code: ");
    String resortCode = console.nextLine();
    for(Resort re: resortList)
    {
        if ( re.getResortCode().equals(resortCode))
            System.out.println(re.toString());

    }

    Rental r1 = new Rental(guestList.get(2),resortList.get(3));
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(r1);
    System.out.println("");
    console.nextLine();
}
```

Thanks very much for Jason C's Solution. I done with my program.

```
    int guestIndex = -1; 

    for(int i = 0; i <guestList.size(); ++ i)
    {
        if ( guestList.get(i).getPersonId().equals(id)) {

          guestIndex = i;
        }
     }


    int resortIndex = -1; 
    for(int n = 0; n < resortList.size(); ++ n)
    {
      if ( resortList.get(n).getResortCode().equals(resortCode)) {
          System.out.println(re.toString());
          resortIndex = n; 
       }
    }

    Rental r1 = new Rental(guestList.get(guestIndex),resortList.get(resortIndex));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to have a good handle on how to *find* the item you are looking for. To *store* that item for later use, simply stick it in a variable when you find it.

You have this now:

```
for(Resort re: resortList)
{
    if ( re.getResortCode().equals(resortCode))
        System.out.println(re.toString());
}

Rental r1 = new Rental(guestList.get(2),resortList.get(3));
```

But instead you could do something like this:

```
Rental r1 = null; // <= this is where we'll store the found object

for(Resort re: resortList)
{
    if ( re.getResortCode().equals(resortCode)) {
        System.out.println(re.toString());
        r1 = re; // <= keep track of the one we found
    }
}

// now r1 contains the found object, or null if not found
```

If you want to get the index itself, it's probably easiest with a standard for loop:

```
int resortIndex = -1; // <= this is where we'll store the index

for(int n = 0; n < resortList.size(); ++ n)
{
    if ( resortList.get(n).getResortCode().equals(resortCode)) {
        System.out.println(re.toString());
        resortIndex = n; // <= keep track of the index
    }
}

// now resortIndex contains the index into the array, or -1 if not found
```

There are other ways you could improve your code (e.g. `break` as soon as you find the item, etc.) but it's all a bit beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I require resortList and guestList in Rental

Comment: Your second method suitable for my program. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact need, but you can use HashMap to store the values as key values pair. which can reduce your some steps for this particular need

**EDIT**
HashMap: hash map is a data structure which allows you to store the data in a key value pair, so you can fetch the value from the key by using `get` method, and for your case key is the customer id and and value is customer. hash map is very simple to implement read the tutorial bellow.

tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-hashmap-tutorial-java/
documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: I not sure how to use HashMap

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Nixit Patel, solution...I think it would be something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Person> guestList = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();
Map<Integer, Chalet> resortList = new HashMap<Integer, Chalet>();

private void execute() {
    loadList();

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter your id: ");
        String id = console.nextLine();

        Person pe = guestList.get(id);
        if (pe != null) {
            System.out.println(pe.getPersonId());
        } else {
            System.err.println("Person not found: " + id);
        }

        System.out.print("Enter resort code: ");
        String resortCode = console.nextLine();
        Chalet re = resortList.get(resortCode);
        if (re != null) {
            System.out.println(re.getId());
        } else {
            System.err.println("Resort Not found: " + id);
        }

        Rental r1 = new Rental(guestList.get(2), resortList.get(3));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(r1);
        System.out.println("");
        console.nextLine();
    }

}

private void loadList() {
    guestList.put(1, new Person("001", "Alvin", "888999888"));
    guestList.put(2, new Person("002", "Bob", "89888999"));
    guestList.put(3, new Person("003", "Wendy", "989123345"));


    resortList.put(1, new Chalet("001", "chalet1", 90));
    resortList.put(2, new Chalet("002", "chalet2", 90));
    resortList.put(3, new Chalet("003", "chalet3", 85));
    resortList.put(4, new Chalet("004", "chalet4", 80));
    resortList.put(5, new Chalet("005", "chalet5", 80));
    resortList.put(6, new Chalet("006", "chalet6", 70));
}
```